# Identity properties with auto-implemented getters

Tags: c#, properties, system.reflection

I am looking to identify [auto-implemented properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) on a class that have a getter, as compared to other properties' getters which use some other state to determine their values.

For example, take the follow class:

```
public class RgbColor {

    public int Red { get; }
    public int Green { get; }
    public int Blue { get; }

    public string Hex => String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", this.Red, this.Green, this.Blue);
    public bool IsBlack { get { return this.Red == 0 && this.Green == 0 && this.Blue == 0; } }
    public bool IsWhite { get { return this.isWhite; } }

    private bool isWhite;

    public RgbColor(int red, int green, int blue) {
        this.Red = red;
        this.Green = green;
        this.Blue = blue;

        this.isWhite = (this.Red == 255 && this.Green == 255 && this.Blue == 255);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to detect that, in the above example, the getters for `Red`, `Green` and `Blue` are defined using auto-implemented properties, and the getters for `Hex`, `IsWhite`, and `IsBlack` are not?

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection:

```
public static bool IsAutoProperty(this PropertyInfo prop)
{
    return prop.DeclaringType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic |BindingFlags.Instance).
           Any(p => p.Name.Contains("<" + prop.Name + ">"));
}
```